# Tag merging and synonyms

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

> ***Moderator's Note:*** I am (at least) temporarily closing this thread.  New suggestions should be made in the current [Winter tag cleanup](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12485/8348) meta-thread.

---

This is half a question, half an announcement.  I will be going through the list of tags and merging particularly bad ones (e.g. ones that aren't mathematical or are too specific) into the tag [tag-removed].  I will also be creating tag synonyms.  Any suggestions for mergers or synonyms should go into this thread.

Roughly speaking, here is my general policy: if I can't imagine a person classifying a tag as either interesting or ignored, I'm getting rid of it.

**Edit:** This thread and the tag changes archive have been merged for simplicity.

**Edit2:** I've started a new summary thread. Moderators: please allow sufficient time (at least 1 day) for discussion on "non-trivial" proposals, before actual implementation (some of such "non-trivial" ones are still not yet resolved, see the list below). After implementation please first *comment* to indicate implementation (to get a date stamp), then *delete* the answer to unclutter, and *add* a line to the summary thread.

Comment: Changes are automatically recorded at  http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=master , but for changes initiated by moderators please also post them as answers in this thread so that they can be voted and commented upon.  In theory, reversal or a different synonym might be a result of the discussion in some cases. (In practice, the moderator judgements have been reasonable as one can see at that link.)

Comment: I deleted two tag synonyms experimentally, but unfortunately I do not remember what they are.  Anyone who misses them enough to remember them should post it in this thread and let it be voted on.

Comment: @T..: should I also report on the tags I've merged?

Comment: I think it's good practice to document any changes if it's not completely annoying to do so.  Maybe a separate "tag changes history" thread can be the archive and this one for the suggestions.  This is just my preference, I have no idea what others might think, but because the tag system already contains some evolved structure it seems like any modification should be documented.  This might also be useful for other purposes later.

Comment: @T..: I'm not so sure.  Most of what I'll be doing is essentially garbage-collection and I don't think that's worth documenting.  Anything that's not obviously garbage-collection I'll propose in this thread.

Comment: Also, I have the feeling that decisions on tags will often arise after a certain amount of back and forth about competing proposals (see e.g. the current discussion on [cardinals] or the earlier one that led to [elementary-set-theory]) and it is easy to forget the logic of the decision later on.  The tag system is part of the knowledge-organization function performed by the site, so it could be very interesting over time to see how the choices are made and what principles can be distilled from the process.

Comment: re: garbage collection, individual decisions might be trivial but taken cumulatively there may be non-obvious decisions to be made, patterns noticed or design criteria articulated.  It would suffice to have a single "garbage tags" posting (list each removed tag plus number of times it was used) that keeps growing from the garbage collection in progress, but visibility of the changes has its own value.  Simply knowing the fraction and nature of junk tags is useful for considering the future evolution of the tag system.

Comment: Thanks for the additional thread. May I suggest the format "[original tag], change, number of postings affected, sample link".

Comment: @T..: in order for the changes to actually be reversible I think I should link to all of the affected questions.  (The reversibility isn't perfect, though; to restore tags you have to bump all of the affected questions, which is annoying.)

Comment: ah.  That could be labor intensive in some cases.  Does SE2.0 retain the original tag set for a posting, or any changes are in-place overwrites?

Comment: Qiaochu, does merging [A] to [B] prevent future use of [A], or is it just a search-and-replace of A's to B's in the current tag environment?

Comment: @T..: the latter.

Comment: why are people downvoting? also, this is much better idea than the previous one.

Comment: If I want to suggest a retag on several questions without having them bumped up, is this the place? It regards to my old request about cardinals/large-cardinals tags. I think that my questions on the former should be transfered to the latter, and most questions on the latter (read: except for my questions) should be transfered to the former.

Comment: @Asaf: yes.  I'm not familiar with this cardinals request, so could you also post that here?

Comment: @Qiaochu: You did comment on it, you should probably be familiar with this request: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1347 but I will post links to specific questions in an answer here.

Comment: This seems to have gotten absolutely unreadable.  I think we'd be much better off with each request in its own question.

Comment: @Isaac: why? The problem with doing that is that it puts an upper bound on how many requests can be made in a certain timeframe without cluttering up meta. This way people are free to request as many changes as they like.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Because it takes too long to figure out what's new or changed when this monster-question gets bumped to the top.  If one person has many tag changes to suggest, they can post them all in one meta question if they want, but I think we'd be more likely to get useful information from answers on such questions and votes on the question and answers if each suggestion were its own question.

Comment: @Qiaochu ...And comments in new answers are folded immediately (because there are too many comments in total) — I second the idea of starting new thread or something

Comment: By mistake, I created a tag for diaphontine-equations. I fixed the question that used it.  Please delete the tag.

Comment: New thread: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12485/

Comment: This question is now superseded by the [Winter tag cleanup](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12485/8348) thread.

Answer (score 15):

***Summary Thread for Implemented Changes***

(Please do not edit this answer unless you are a moderator. All proposed changes should be added as new answers to the question. Users with 10K+ reputation will still be able to see the original dates of proposals and implementations.)

One should also note that there [exists a page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) on the StackExchange platform specifically listing all tag synonyms and proposals for tag synonyms. Any user with [2.5K+ rep can go and vote up/down proposals](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) for synonyms.

The following is sorted alphabetically by the name of the deprecated tag. Format is "(deprecated tag name) s/m (principal tag name)" in the case of synonyms or mere merging without synonyms; and "(deprecated tag name) d" in the case of removed tag names.

- [action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action) d
- [addition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addition) s [arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)
- [ag.algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ag.algebraic-geometry) m [algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-geometry)
- [analytic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic) m [analyticity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analyticity)
- [art-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art-theory) m [art](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art)
- [bases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bases) d
- [big-o](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-o) s [asymptotics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptotics)
- [books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) s [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)
- [bundles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bundles) d
- [cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardinality) m [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory)
- [closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closure) d
- [complex-conjugate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-conjugate) m [complex-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-numbers)
- [complex-variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-variables) s [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis)
- [complexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity) s [computational-complexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-complexity)
- [continuum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuum) m [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis)
- [counter-examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-examples) s [examples-counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples-counterexamples)
- [convex-sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-sets) s [convex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-analysis)
- [differential-manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-manifold) m [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry)
- [division-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/division-algebra) m [division-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/division-algebras)
- [elementary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary) d
- [elementary-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-geometry) m [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)
- [ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ellipse) s [conic-sections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conic-sections)
- [enumeration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumeration) s [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)
- [equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equations) d
- [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples) s [examples-counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples-counterexamples)
- [expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expectation) m [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability)
- [explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/explanation) s [intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuition)
- [exterior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exterior) d
- [field-extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-extensions) m [field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-theory)
- [golay-code](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golay-code) m [coding-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-theory)
- [gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradient) d
- [group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group) m [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory)
- [hyperbolic-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperbolic-functions) m [trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry)
- [impossibility-proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/impossibility-proof) d
- [infinite-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-series) m [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series)
- [iterated-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iterated-functions) m [dynamical-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamical-systems)
- [jargon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jargon) s [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)
- [lie-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lie-algebra) s [lie-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lie-algebras)
- [linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear) m [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra)
- [linear-combination](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-combination) m [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra)
- [manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold) s [manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifolds)
- [materials-science](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials-science) d
- [measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measure) d
- [metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metric) s [metric-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metric-spaces)
- [middle-school](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-school) d
- [mobius-strip](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-strip) d
- [mobius-transforms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-transforms) m [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis)
- [normal-distibution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normal-distibution) m [normal-distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normal-distribution)
- [numeral-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numeral-systems) s [number-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-systems)
- [numerical-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis) s [numerical-methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods)
- [parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parabola) s [conic-sections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conic-sections)
- [pedagogy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy) s [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching)
- [primitive-polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primitive-polynomial) m [polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials)
- [progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/progression) s [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series)
- [properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/properties) d
- [putnam](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/putnam) s [contest-math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest-math)
- [pythagorean-triples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pythagorean-triples) d
- (ramanujan) d
- [random-variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-variable) m [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability)
- [real](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) m [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis)
- [recursion-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursion-theory) s [computability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computability)
- [riddle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle) s [puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle)
- [riemann-surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riemann-surface) s [riemann-surfaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riemann-surfaces)
- [rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings) s [ring-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-theory)
- [semi-group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semi-group) s [semi-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semi-groups)
- [sigma-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sigma-algebra) s [measure-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measure-theory)
- [signal-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-analysis) s [signal-processing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing)
- [sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sum) d
- [summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation) m [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series)
- [symbolism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism) m [notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation)
- [theoretical-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-mathematics) d
- [topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topology) s [general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology)
- [uniform-distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uniform-distribution) m [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability)
- [wedge-product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wedge-product) s [exterior-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exterior-algebra)
- [wolframalpha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolframalpha) s [wolfram-alpha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha)

Comment: Awesome; thanks for doing this, Willie!

Comment: I do not like the alphabetically ordering. Is it possible to add another answer with chronological log as well? Alphabetical makes it impossible to find with a glance the last merges and whatnot.

Comment: @Asaf: click on the "edited 4 hours ago" and read the diff. It is more succinct, and has guaranteed correct date/time-stamps. Alphabetical makes it easier for *me* to check whether a tag that I am suspicious of has been discussed before and deleted before.

Comment: @Willie: I know how to get there. I was hoping there could be another answer with a chronological wangdangdoodle of the merges. Do you mind if I add such answer and manage it?

Comment: @Asaf: sure, go ahead if you'd like to do the work. Thanks, btw, for offering to help!

Comment: Apart from merging and removing tags, some tags were "divided" - replaced by two new tags. 
I know of [algebra](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2434/) and [lattices](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3187/), as of this moment.
Should changes of this kind be included into the list?

Comment: On an unrelated note, I've seen an announcement that Willie and Zev are taking break from the moderator duties for some time. (I hope they'll come back later.) So far Willie did all edits to this post. Is some other moderator going to take care of this list? (It explicitly states: *Please do not edit this answer unless you are a moderator.* I suppose there is some good reason for this; probably other users don't see all changes made by moderators.)

Answer (score 9):

[Edit]
Within the last month somebody has created a tag [error-correcting-codes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-correcting-codes).
There are currently 9 questions with this tag. I would propose to synonymize this with
[coding-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-theory). The latter "mother tag" has only 223 questions itself, so I don't see the need to splinter off a handful of questions.

As I don't have a score of +5 in [error-correcting-codes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-correcting-codes) I cannot suggest a synonym at this time. Instead I will reach for the fine-tuning sledgehammer of manually removing this tag. If somebody objects, let me know.

If the tag reappears, I will bring it up again and/or flag a moderator.
[/Edit]

During my first 3 weeks here I have encountered a few peculiarities:

The tag [golay-code](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golay-code) has only a single post. I don't know for how long we commonly wait to have meaningful statistical evidence, but it sounds like a merger with [coding-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-theory) is due.

Another thing that I found odd was the tag [division-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/division-algebra). Of the 5 posts carrying that tag one was about octonions, the rest were (junior) high school level questions about the role of division in school level algebra. I rather got that the intention of the tag was to collect questions related to division algebras aka skewfields aka division rings, but I may be wrong. The confusion may stem from the fact that this tag has no wiki entry. If it is meant to be part of [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra), then I could write a wiki for it.

Comment: Okay, 'golay-code' has been removed (I think it is too specific), the weird 'division-algebra' questions have been retagged. I've renamed 'division-algebra' to 'division-algebras' (note the plural) to be more in accord with our general tendency of using plural forms for objects in the tags.

Comment: Thank you for keeping an eye out for these, and I would like to take you up on your offer of writing a tag-wiki for division-algebras (it should be a part of abstract algebra). If you drop me an @-notification when you do that, I'll approve the Wiki proposal ASAP.

Answer (score 9):

Do we really need both the [integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration) and [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral) tags?

If not, could we merge one into the other?

And if so, could someone give a good explanation of the difference between the two?

---

Edit by J.M.: If we do merge these two, which name do we keep? (A rewrite of the tag blurb and tag wiki might also be in order.)

Comment: I think this has to do with [this thread by Bill](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2028/), see also [his answer here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393/).

Comment: @t.b.: Thanks.  I'm pretty sure I had read that post at some point, but I had forgotten about it.  It looks like his suggestion was only partly implemented, though: We now have [tag:integration], [tag:integral], and [tag:definite-integral]!  Or was [tag:integration] the choice of name for questions involving indefinite integration?

Comment: At this moment tag info for integral is: _Questions on the evaluation of definite and indefinite integrals._ For integration: _All aspects of integration, including the definition of the integral and computing indefinite integrals (antiderivatives)._ So it seems to me that [tag:integration] was intended for "theoretical" question and [tag:integral] for computations, but they were definitely not used in this way.

Comment: This was also discussed in a [separate question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9684/tags-integral-and-integration). Obviously, I've forgotten about this post, when I was posting that question.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning here that the two tags now [are synonyms](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/integration/synonyms).

Answer (score 9):

Can we please delete [proof-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy)?

This feels like a meta tag.

Comment: BTW there is a separate question [Tags (proof-strategy) and (proof-writing)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/). Unfortunately with no answers (at the moment).

Answer (score 7):

By the tag wiki, it looks like [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) and [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) are being used the same way. Should the former be deprecated in favor of the other?

Also, there has been [previous discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473) on this topic, but it seems that no conclusion was reached.

Should the question be brought up again on meta.math?

---

EDIT (M.S.): As you have probably noticed, [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) is empty now (already for some time).

---

EDIT (J.M.): That damn [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) tag has kept popping up the last few days... I've been able to remove it, but it seems I'm the only guy who gives a rat's ass about these things...

(Later)

Maybe that last bit was somewhat harsh. The thing popping up just had me frustrated. I do remember asking if we can have a blacklist for it, and Willie said that he'd rather hope that people would be smart enough not to use that tag again. Oh well.

(Much later)

I see somebody bothered to write a tag-wiki (again?!) but didn't bother to remove said tag from the questions... maybe I should stop caring; it just raises my blood pressure.

---

EDIT (M.S.): [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) tag [has been blacklisted](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6299/should-the-algebra-tag-be-blacklisted) already some time ago. Most regular users probably know about this, but I guess it is worth adding the information to this post, too.

Comment: Ugh. Some of the questions are [abstract-algebra] and some of them are [algebra-precalculus]. That is annoying.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I think a small minority (10% or so) are [algebra-precalculus]. I can go through and help with manually retagging, if you think it's a good idea.

Comment: 10% from ~600 is still 60 questions. This would cause a tsunami of old questions to wash over the front page if done at once. If you do retag the rogue questions, please limit the amount of retagged questions to 10 or so every day (and please do that in some interval as well to allow new questions rise again).

Comment: @Asaf: Will do – I will go oldest to newest, 2-3 questions every 4-6 hours.

Comment: I'll try to continue in retagging algebra questions. Hopefully doing it twice a week, each time approximately 10 questions, will not cause too much trouble. I know this might be annoying, particularly to the people browsing abstract-algebra and algebra-precalculus tags, but it is probably the only way to do this. (Originally I started at the rate 10-15 questions a day, which was probably too much.)

Comment: @Martin: thanks for doing this. That sounds very reasonable.

Comment: @J.M. I often see that and edit as well, I don't think you're the only one who cares. I was just preoccupied with other things on the site lately...

Comment: @Asaf, no worries. I see you have your hands full on somebody. ;)

Comment: @J.M. It seems that this time a few questions with the tag were left on purpose - so that the tag-wiki with the warning will not be lost. See [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5945992#5945992). I'm sorry about your blood pressure.

Answer (score 7):

### ***Chronological Summary Thread for Implemented Changes***

Taking on Willie's notation, the following is sorted chronologically by the time  (newer is higher) of the action taken. Format is "(deprecated tag name) s/m (principal tag name)" in the case of synonyms or mere merging without synonyms; and "(deprecated tag name) d" in the case of removed tag names.

**July, 2011**

*July, 9th*

- [riemann-surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riemann-surface) s [riemann-surfaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riemann-surfaces)

*July 7th*

- [jargon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jargon) s [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

*July 6th*

- [lie-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lie-algebra) s [lie-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lie-algebras)

*July 5th*

- [theoretical-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-mathematics) d
- [differential-manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-manifold) m [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry)
- [linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear) m [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra)
- [linear-combination](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-combination) m [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra)

**Actions B.C.**

- [action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action) d
- [ag.algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ag.algebraic-geometry) m [algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-geometry)
- [bases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bases) d
- [big-o](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-o) s [asymptotics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptotics)
- [books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) s [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)
- [cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardinality) m [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory)
- [complex-variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-variables) s [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis)
- [continuum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuum) m [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis)
- [division-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/division-algebra) m [division-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/division-algebras)
- [elementary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary) d
- [elementary-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-geometry) m [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)
- [ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ellipse) s [conic-sections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conic-sections)
- [enumeration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumeration) s [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)
- [equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equations) d
- [expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expectation) m [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability)
- [explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/explanation) s [intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuition)
- [field-extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-extensions) m [field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-theory)
- [golay-code](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golay-code) m [coding-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-theory)
- [gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradient) d
- [group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group) m [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory)
- [hyperbolic-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperbolic-functions) m [trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry)
- [impossibility-proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/impossibility-proof) d
- [iterated-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iterated-functions) m [dynamical-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamical-systems)
- [linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear) m [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra)
- [materials-science](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials-science) d
- [measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measure) d
- [metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metric) s [metric-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metric-spaces)
- [mobius-strip](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-strip) d
- [mobius-transforms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-transforms) m [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis)
- [normal-distibution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normal-distibution) m [normal-distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normal-distribution)
- [numerical-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis) s [numerical-methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods)
- [parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parabola) s [conic-sections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conic-sections)
- [pedagogy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy) s [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching)
- [primitive-polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primitive-polynomial) m [polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials)
- [progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/progression) s [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series)
- [properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/properties) d
- [pythagorean-triples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pythagorean-triples) d
- [random-variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-variable) m [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability)
- [real](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) m [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis)
- [recursion-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursion-theory) s [computability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computability)
- [rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings) s [ring-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-theory)
- [semi-group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semi-group) s [semi-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semi-groups)
- [signal-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-analysis) s [signal-processing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing)
- [sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sum) d
- [summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation) m [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series)
- [symbolism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism) m [notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation)
- [topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topology) s [general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology)
- [uniform-distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uniform-distribution) m [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability)
- [wedge-product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wedge-product) s [exterior-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exterior-algebra)

Comment: Instead of B.C., I think it should be B.A.K.! Thanks!

Comment: @Willie: B.C. stands for Before Caring (about it) :-)

Answer (score 7):

I proposed creating [partial-differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-differential-equations) as a synonym for [pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pde) in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8314043#8314043), where it met with some support. Rationale:

- [pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pde) is about the only commonly used tag which is an abbreviation. Judging from the other tags they see, new users would not expect abbreviations in tags.
- While "PDE" is a completely standard abbreviation for mathematicians, it is less so for students in service-level courses, who supply a large number of PDE questions.
- When a user tries to tag their question with (partial-diff...) and finds no match, they are likely to delete "partial" and mistag the question as (differential-equations). This is one of the more common mistags I see.

Comment: That said, I could not figure out how tag synonyms are created, so this is left up to the more knowledgeable people.

Comment: If you have "enough" reputation in the particular tag, you can suggest a synonym.

Comment: Go to the tag page [tag:pde], click [synonyms](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/pde/synonyms), enter "partial-differential-equations" in the Suggest box.

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks! Now I see why this synonym wasn't created before: the 25 character limit for tags. Grr. // So I tried to suggest [tag:partial-differential-eqns] which would serve the same purpose: users would see it when beginning to type "partial-di". Failure #2: "the suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a synonym".

Comment: Well, there are two ways of this, either create the tag by tagging at least one questions by it (the tag can be removed after the synonym had been suggested), or ask a moderator, who can create synonym (without waiting for votes from users to approve the synonym).

Comment: Okay, done. (That 25 character limit is the original reason why I chose (pde) instead of (partial...). )

Answer (score 7):

Can we kill the [completeness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/completeness) tag? A look at the five questions currently tagged as such already indicates two-and-a-half different meanings for (completeness). That is without considering geodesic completeness in geometry, completeness of logical systems, completeness of vector fields, completeness of measure spaces, completeness of an orthonormal set of vectors in a Hilbert space, completeness for graphs, completeness of partially ordered sets, ... and I am sure there must be others.

**Edit: [A.K]:** March $10^{\text{th}}$, I have ruthlessly butchered this tag away!

**Edit II [A.K]:** March $20^{\text{th}}$, I have killed the tag *again*. Please remove it, and/or point to this post when it comes back to life the next time.

Comment: I agree: `completeness` as a tag is just as useless as `normality` or `regularity`.

Comment: Yes! I mentioned that to M Sina in a comment to one of the edits, but apparently that comment was unnoticed. Completeness is overly broad, similarly I think that [tag:diagonalization] is bad.

Comment: @Asaf: can you post a separate request for diagonalization? Exposing my ignorance here, besides the Cantor variety and the one in linear algebra/functional analysis, what other things are called diagonalization?

Comment: @Willie: Cantor's method extends pretty much everywhere in logic and set theory. Godel's incompleteness proof is essentially by diagonalization, for example.

Comment: @Asaf: Would it be acceptable to have two tags instead: (matrix-diagonalization) and (cantor-diagonalization)?

Comment: @Willie: I don't see why the set theoretical counterpart needs a tag to begin with; but I also don't see why the linear algebra one needs a tag either.

Comment: @Asaf: just fishing for ideas.

Comment: I am not a lake. Or a river. :-)

Comment: Fine. I posted that as another answer.

Answer (score 6):

I find [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) lacking in utility.  It seems that every post which has this tag is either closed or could easily be retagged.  I would be happy to suggest alternative tags for posts tagged as [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number).

---

*EDIT by Srivatsan (Nov 29):* Bumping up the post. I propose that we start removing the [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) tag from posts.

Comment: A large portion of those questions need to be retagged manually. A first step maybe to retag the ones that have *only* numbers and nothing else as the tag.

Comment: @Willie Is there a way to find all such questions, btw?

Comment: @Grigory: not that I know of besides going through the entire list. But for (number), there is only 1 (I just checked now, makes my earlier comment a bit silly).

Comment: @Willie I see. (No idea what tags this one should have, but IMO it's offtopic -- voted to close.)

Comment: [tag:number] tag is out of the system.

Comment: BTW the number tag [has been blacklisted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10302/how-about-we-blacklist-number/22558#22558).

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion [propositional-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propositional-calculus) and recently created tag [propositional-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propositional-logic) should be synonyms.

(If the intended use of [propositional-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propositional-logic) is different, it should be clarified in tag-wiki, which is currently empty. Based on two questions which currently have this tag, I think the usage is the same as [propositional-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propositional-calculus), therefore I made the above proposal. If you think that these two tags should have different purpose, please, explain it in the comments and consider editing tag-wiki.)

Comment: I support that, and have suggested a synonym.

Answer (score 6):

I think [context-free-grammar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context-free-grammar) should be merged into and synonymized to [context-free-language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context-free-language).

Comment: Hmm... a context free language is generated by context free grammar; I am not exactly sure we want the arrow to go the direction you proposed. Can you explain briefly why the arrow should go one way, and not the other? Thanks!

Comment: I agree with you. When I wrote the proposal I was not thinking that the merge was asymmetric.

Comment: Okay, I'll do the merge now.

Answer (score 6):

Something that has been bugging me for a while:

There is a [rootsystem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rootsystem) tag, while the correct form would be [root-system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/root-system). Given that there are currently only 16 questions in this tag, it won't be too hard to correct this.

Thoughts?

---

> **Update:** [rootsystem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rootsystem) has been merged into [root-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/root-systems).

Comment: It should probably be [tag:root-systems], in plural. You have 6 upvotes and 0 downvotes; I say go for it.

Answer (score 5):

I think the current tag [recursive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursive) is not as good as [recurrence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recurrence) or even better [recurrence-relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recurrence-relation).

Comment: Perhaps change them all to (recursion)?

Comment: The official name I learned from books is recurrence relation, not recursion.

Comment: @Tim: The tags, if I recall correctly also dip into recursion theory at times.

Comment: How are recurrence relation and recursion theory related, and how do they differ?

Comment: @Asaf @Tim: since this comment thread is getting off topic, I'm removing the posts to leave the discussion on topic. Cheers!

Comment: This is annoying. Some of the questions tagged [recursive] are about recursive functions but some are about recurrence relations. I think this one may have to be done manually.

Comment: If they are about computable function they should be retagged as "computability". I will leave a separate comment about the "recursion theory" tag that should also be merged to "computability".

Comment: @Tim: they are completely unrelated. I think this tag should be deleted, and its tagged questions retagged. But I don't know whether that can be done without bumping all the questions.

Answer (score 5):

> The two tags, (eigenvalues) and (eigenvectors) have now both been marked as synonyms to [eigenvalues-eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eigenvalues-eigenvectors). I have to remove the word "and" from Douglas Stones's suggestion because of the 25 character length limit on tag names.

I don't see the need for having both [eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eigenvalues) and [eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eigenvectors) as separate tags.

Potential names for the merged tag: (eigensystems), (eigenanalysis), (eigendecomposition). If there are better terms for this, please propose them in the comments.

[Here is some relevant empirical data from the Google Ngram Viewer.](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=eigensystem%2Ceigenanalysis%2Ceigendecomposition&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

---

I like Douglas S. Stones's suggestion (eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors), which neatly mirrors the existing tag [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series).

Comment: May I then propose the more general [tag:eigensystems] if these two are merged?

Comment: @J.M.: *Eigensystem*, *eigenanalysis*, *eigendecomposition*... Is there a standard established term for this?

Comment: @J.M., Rahul: We can go informal with [eigen-stuff] :-)

Comment: "Eigendecomposition" is sorta kinda long, so I'd go with "eigensystem" myself. But I'm down with an explanation of why other terms would be better...

Comment: @J.M.: I added some empirical data up there. But looking at it I still can't form a clear opinion on which is best.

Comment: I personally like (eigen-decomposition) better as the primary tag. I can of course Syn. eigensystem, eigenvalues, eigenvectors all to the primary tag, whichever it is that we choose in the end.

Comment: Perhaps [eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors]?  I think [Eigen-decomposition] would not immediately suggest eigenvalues and eigenvectors to e.g. students encountering eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the first time.

Answer (score 5):

I think the posts tagged as [real-number-computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-number-computation) can probably be retagged also, and this tag should be deleted.

Comment: [tag:real-number-computation] is empty now. Thanks to Eugene for [helping](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5071639#5071639) with emptying this tag.

Answer (score 5):

Please merge [paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paradox) (66q) into [paradoxes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paradoxes) (2q), so as to match the established tag pluralisation convention.

The tag wiki and excerpt from [paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paradox) are better, though, so maybe they need to be carried over somehow.

> **Update**: This merge has been processed. Thanks Arthur Fischer!

Comment: I was coming to post this request. Perhaps the right way to do it is to merge the new into the old, and then rename the old one.

Comment: So this seems unproblematic and uncontroversial.  I'll go ahead an transfer [tag:paradox]'s tag-wiki and excerpt to [tag:paradoxes], and then merge/synonymise.... [3 mins later: done]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not too keen about the [birthday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birthday) tag; something like [calendar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) might be more suitable, unless one has a better name for the tag we can assign to calendrical questions.

Comment: I am somewhat tempted to just delete the tag altogether. A lot of the birthday questions are just probability/combinatorics. Much of classical mathematics (esp. those developed with relation to astronomy) are actually closely tied to the study of calendar systems, but of the questions currently with the birthday tag, I don't think any falls in that category.

Comment: @Willie: I won't mind a deletion; I threw this out because I'm not comfy with it, but have no solutions (to propose) for it.

Comment: I've removed the birthday tags from most of the questions, and added a 'calendar-computations' tag for the few that is appropriate (if the question's answer uses the Doomsday algorithm in some way, for example.)

Comment: @Willie: Sounds good to me. :)

Answer (score 4):

I find the tag [natural-number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-number) unneeded, with only 11 questions tagged under it, some of these questions belong to [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory) (however tagged under [set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-theory)) and others fit well under currently available tags.

I see no actual use of the tag for real questions that are not fitting well and properly under other tags of the currently tagged questions.

It should be deleted after verification that all questions fit under other tags currently present, personally I think it is fine (except for one question tagged only under [natural-number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-number) which I am uncertain how to classify).

Comment: I think most [tag:natural-number] questions would fit well in [tag:elementary-number-theory].

Answer (score 4):

[inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inversion) is quite the mess; some of it is for inverting matrices and some of it is for inverting functions. I'm not really pushing for a deletion, but is there a neat way to resolve this?

---

*Added [by Srivatsan]:* I propose to delete the [inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverse) tag.

This tag is currently used in a variety of different senses: inverse of a ring/group element, matrix inverse, function inverse, inverse Laplace transform,  inverse cdf, etc. However, it seems that all 30 questions under the tag are safely covered by the other tags.

Comment: Just classify that as inversion within rings or something that generalizes both instances and more! :-)

Comment: I don't see the problem: deep below the surface they are all the same thing. I am however in favour of a tag wiki that briefly mentions inversion as an abstract concept and asks the user to specify the regime where the idea is used in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I am very much unfamiliar with the topics, however do we really need both [3-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3-manifolds) and [4-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4-manifolds)?

**Edit:**
As we agreed that [low-dimensional-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-dimensional-topology) is better, I wonder... what is the difference between that and [manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold)? I'm certain that some difference exists to justify the two tags to be separated. Is it possible for someone to write it into the Tag Wikis (esp. into the excerpts) to help [me] distinguish between the two?

**Edit II:**
The tag [3-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3-manifolds) came back. I tried synonymizing it with [low-dimensional-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-dimensional-topology), alas [I could not since there is only one question in the tag with one vote and no answers. So in fact, no one can suggest a synonym!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2925/a-rep-threshold-to-override-the-synonyms-rep)

Comment: Both should become `(low-dimensional-topology)`, maybe?

Comment: @Grigory: I like that idea.

Comment: (Re: edit) Huh? Most questions in [tag:manifolds] about manifolds of arbitrary dimension and have nothing to do with low-dimensional topology. (In any case, adding tag wikis would be nice, of course.)

Comment: @Grigory: I figured as much, I don't *really* know the difference. Since the original tags were 3/4-manifolds, I would expect this all to have something to do with manifolds...

Comment: @Grigory: one might think about merging (manifold) into (differential-geometry) (I don't really see the difference). There is some cleaning up required before doing so, though.

Comment: @Theo: Are you that one? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: well manifolds can have any dimension you like :) low-dimensional topology is specifically knot theory, 3-manifold and 4-manifold topology. E.g. [Thurston](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Thurston), [Freedman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Freedman), [Donaldson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Donaldson), [Witten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Witten) to name a few of the most famous guys (you know Perelman, I guess).

Comment: @Asaf: I didn't quite get your joke. No I was just tagging a few obvious candidates (and one false positive) with the new (low-dimensional-topology) tag. Before I go ahead I'd like to see others' opinion.

Comment: @Grigory: that's what I meant with cleaning up.

Comment: No, (manifolds) should not be merged into (differential-geometry): manifolds are not required to have a smooth structure. Low dimensional topology has a set of tools separate from higher and lower dimensional topology. In one and two dimensions, one can always equip manifolds with a smooth structure, and those smooth structure always give rise to Riemannian/conformal structures, so topology is completely determined by geometry. In higher dimensions the topology is too malleable that a lot of weird stuff can happen. 3 and 4 dimensions is "just right".

Comment: @Willie: can we move this discussion [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/2804#2804)?

Comment: For example, you can think about the equivalent of the Poincare conjecture in all dimensions. Dimension 1 is trivial. Dimension 2 is contained in Riemann mapping theorem. Dimension 5 and higher can be dealt with using h-cobordism. Dimension 4 was solved separately by Freedman, and dimension 3 Perelman's proof uses so much geometry that it leaves some topologists unsatisfied.

Answer (score 4):

The tag [expected-value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expected-value) was recently created.  We used to have an [expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expectation) tag, but we decided that it was sufficiently covered by [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability), and so [expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expectation) was merged into [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) several months back.  In keeping with this decision, I think [expected-value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expected-value) should also be merged with [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability).

Comment: I just looked at the questions tagged with (expected-value). It appears to me that a couple of them perhaps should be tagged (probability-theory) instead of (probability). What do you think?

Comment: @Willie: Good point.  Of the 5 that are currently tagged [tag:expected-value], I think the two that are also tagged (probability-theory) should still be tagged (probability-theory) and not also tagged (probability).  The other three should be tagged (probability).

Comment: @Willie: I removed the "expected-value" tag from the two that should be tagged "probability-theory."  It should be fine now to merge "expected-value" with "probability."

Comment: Okay, I've made the merge.

Comment: I will just mention that there is a new question on meta related to this tag and some similar tags: [Expectation means average?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28381) (Since I see that @WillieWong was involved in this previous discussion, perhaps also a ping is warranted - in case you're interested in this new tag-related discussion.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: thanks for the ping! I don't really have much to add to the great discussion already going on there, besides perhaps to note that this merge was implemented at a much simpler time when we stood a chance in the fights against the proliferation of tags. Nowadays with the traffic I may argue for using more and more specific tags.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't [convex-sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-sets) and [convex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-analysis) be synonyms?

<strike>*Updated*: As Willie Wong suggests, the more general tag "convexity" would probably be even better.</strike>

*Updated, again*: On further reflection, I think [convex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-analysis) is the better general term.  We already have 9 other tags called "[something]-analysis", and so [convex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-analysis) would be more consistent with our already-existing tags than [convexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convexity) would.

Comment: I wonder if a more general name like "convexity" would be a better umbrella term. What do people think?

Comment: I'm down with [tag:convexity], unless you guys have better suggestions...

Comment: @Willie: Since nobody else has weighed in on this, why don't you go ahead and make either "convex-analysis" or "convexity" the general term, depending on whether you are convinced by my last update to my answer. :)

Comment: Done. Now if Mike or @J.M. will propose a Tag-wiki for convex-analysis, we'd be all set. (I opted for convex-analysis after realising that we still have a very useful third tag (convex-optimization) which I don't think should be merged with these two.)

Comment: @Willie: Thanks.  I'll propose a tag-wiki for convex-analysis.

Answer (score 4):

Do we need [contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradiction)? Its contents seem... random and unrelated.

Assume by contradiction that we do, since it exists the contradiction hypothesis holds and therefore it is a contradiction!

I propose eradicating this tag completely.

Answer (score 4):

Both [presentation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentation) and [group-presentation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-presentation) are used for the same topic, the later has now a nice [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/group-presentation/info) (thanks to [Alexander Gruber](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/326310/revisions)). I think they should be synonyms.

EDIT: They are [synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) now. (Thanks to Willie Wong.)

Comment: It seems that this proposal has received some support. Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation in either of the two tags to be able to suggest a synonym. (You need at least 5 upvotes.)

Comment: I've merged the two tags and made them synonyms.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for doing that. Should this post be deleted, so that the thread is not too long? (At least for <10k users.)

Comment: Sure! Off and on I've been cleaning up this thread by deleting completed requests. I've not had the opportunity recently to go through them and edit all the changes into the ChangeLog answer, however, and I apologize for my lack of time.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest the synonym (categories) for [category-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/category-theory). I already suggested it on the tag's about-page some time ago, but it didn't receive any attention, so far.

Comment: Done. Remember that voting for synonyms are only available to mods and those with sufficient reputation in the tag.

Answer (score 4):

Some candidates for pluralization. In the following two cases, pluralization would  make tags more [consistent with MO](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12307/mo-mse-tag-incompatibility?noredirect=1#comment48114_12307) in addition to improving internal consistency of tags:

- [limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit) should be  [limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits)
- [group-ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-ring) should be [group-rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-rings)

And a couple more:

- [lagrange-multiplier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lagrange-multiplier) should be [lagrange-multipliers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lagrange-multipliers). A standard usage of the term is *the method of Lagrange multipliers*.
- [extension-field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extension-field) should be [extension-fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extension-fields), with a synonym "field-extension" since the latter order of words is also common.

Comment: I'd certainly prefer "field-extension(s)" to "extension-field(s)"...

Answer (score 3):

This is a good initiative. Please have a look at my [old question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/renaming-tags-to-plurals) and make decisions for the tags mentioned therein.

Comment: I can create the synonyms, but I'm not sure I can change the master tags if they're not already created without bumping a question.  I'll think about it.

Comment: @Qiaochu: at least in SE 1.0, you can rename a tag with a completely new name, but it's pretty counterintuitive: *"If the Remove Tag does not exist, the Master Tag will be renamed to the Remove Tag."* See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/merge-tags-feature-did-it-have-to-be-this-user-abusive

Answer (score 3):

There is a [counting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting) tag. I feel it can be merged with the tag [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics). Can a moderator implement this?

Comment: I can't really claim appropriate expertise here, but on a quick skim, at least a few of the questions tagged [counting] do not seem like combinatorics questions (though certainly the majority do seem like combinatorics questions).

Comment: This question has been discussed before (although I can't remember where now).  There actually is a formal proposal on the tag synonyms page (http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) to make "counting" a synonym for "combinatorics".  Users with 2500+ rep can vote this up or down.

Comment: @Mike You probably meant this discussion: [On the (combinatorics) and (counting) tags.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329/on-the-combinatorics-and-counting-tags).

Answer (score 3):

Is there a need for all three of [k-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/k-theory), [topological-k-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-k-theory) and [algebraic-k-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-k-theory)?

Comment: Apparently there is. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/k-theory-tags-versus-algebraic-k-theory-and-topologica-k-theory

Answer (score 3):

Are we ready to follow up the suggestions in the following answer?

[The tags [recursive] and [recurrence-relation]](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/the-tags-recursive-and-recurrence-relation/2301#2301)

Comment: Didn't someone already do this manually?

Comment: No, please look at Carl's answer. There are some small modifications to be done which can only be done by a moderator.

Comment: Okay, I think that's it.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up, Yuval.  Are all of Carl Mummert's suggestions now implemented?

Comment: The first and third are. The second and fourth are "prescriptive community norms", so it is up to us to implement them.

Answer (score 3):

Do we really need [normal-distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normal-distribution), [geometric-distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-distribution), and [probability-distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-distributions) as three separate tags?

Comment: What is the probability for a question to have any of them? :-)

Comment: I suppose we should retain `(probability-distributions)` and subsume/synonymize the other two...

Comment: @J.M.: I agree.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't [tiling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling) and [tessellations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tessellations) be synonymous?

Comment: By name, yes. But look at the actual questions tagged tessellations. I think some of them are not actually about plane tilings.

Answer (score 3):

How about we kick the bucket on [diagonalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagonalization)? Besides the fact that this is a technique used in linear algebra, this is the name of one of the most prominent proof techniques in logic and set theory (Russell paradox, Cantor's theorem, Incompleteness theorems, existence of $\Gamma$-universal sets for a myriad of pointclasses, and more).

But I also think that as a tag it has no real value, and it mainly clutters the linear algebra related tags. I don't see someone particularly following this tag (I mean, who has a thing for matrix diagonalization? Sure, Rule 36, but still...); and if anyone ever wants to search for it they could use "[linear-algebra] diagonalization" to get sufficient results in a second.

Answer (score 3):

Would it be justified to synonymize [first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-order-logic) and [predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predicate-logic) (both ~100 questions)? [first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-order-logic) as the primary tag seems sensible to me.

Comment: Somewhat related: [this meta-thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8267/8348).

Answer (score 3):

Meta tags:

Please merge [look-and-feel](/questions/tagged/look-and-feel) with [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface).

Comment: The two are now merged.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480/sangaku-a-geometrical-puzzle) was tagged [sangaku].  Merged to [puzzle].

Comment: Sangaku are not puzzles, they are (in most cases) theorems in classical Euclidean geometry.  Suggest to keep it or merge/syn with [euclidean-geometry].

Comment: The question was already tagged "puzzle," so no additional merging or unmerging is necessary.  I can synonymize with [euclidean-geometry] but I don't expect this tag to see much traffic.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14004/convergence-of-series-involving-iterated-sin-closed) was tagged [iteration].  Merged to [tag-removed].

Comment: Could people who downvoted this explain their motives? It seems that somebody must have derived some non-trivial information from seeing the tag [iteration], which, I have to admit, baffles me.

Comment: There have been a number of problems (and presumably more in future) asking for asymptotics of an iteration.  These are purely problems of real or complex analysis with similar methods used in the different solutions;  it is a genre of its own with an interconnected (and cross-linked) body of questions. The answers generally do not use concepts of dynamical systems (invariant measure, ergodicity, chaos, stability, ...) except fixed point.  I think it is more informative to label them as [analysis] [iteration], or the same with [dynamical-systems] as an additional tag, not a replacement.

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate some explanation.  I cannot imagine anyone putting [iteration] as either an interesting-tag or an ignored-tag and, as I explained, that is my primary criterion for removing tags.

Comment: The linked Q&A contains a discussion of why it was difficult to for the OP to locate related questions.  An [iteration] or [iterated-function] tag would have eliminated that difficulty had it been applied to the other questions.  In fact, doing so retroactively would be useful. Dynamical systems is a broad and largely irrelevant category for these questions about single orbits. None of these questions, their answers or the references cited mention dynamical systems (e.g. the famous chapter of De Bruijn's book is on "Iterated Functions").  [Analysis] applies but is a huge category.

Comment: @T..: if you feel strongly enough about this tag you are free to reintroduce it; the moderators don't have a monopoly on that.

Comment: @Qiaochu: as the downvoter, I answered first Alex's question and then your further request for explanation.  Feeling strongly or weakly or any other type of feeling have nothing to do with it; I simply provided some details that were requested about rationale for an [iteration] tag.  The only feeling I'd like to share here is the thought that something much more beneficial for the site culture than any specific decision about tags, is for everyone to avoid discussing, alluding to, or speculating upon users' feelings, motives, thoughts, etc (even in the semi-hypothetical "if you feel X" mode).

Comment: A minor point in case anyone finds it amusing.  I realized after posting that I had not actually downvoted, only intended to do so and reconsidered or never got around to it.  So the "true" downvoter has not explained himself, but may have spoken again through upvotes on the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally created the linear-optimization tag earlier today on this question: [In linear optimization, what does "AP" stand for?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19358/in-linear-optimization-what-does-ap-stand-for).  I have since changed it to the already-existing linear-programming tag, but now we have a linear-optimization tag that doesn't point to anything.  Would you delete the linear-optimization tag?

Comment: [Tags that don't have any associated questions get garbage-collected periodically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it), so you don't have to do anything.

Comment: @Rahul: Thanks.  I'll leave the request up here so others can read your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can anybody give a good reason why the [numerical-methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods) and [numerical-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis) tags are separate? I would say retain one or the other, but certainly not both.

Comment: As an additional note: I think `[numerical-linear-algebra]` is too specific a tag; better that the questions have both the `[linear-algebra]` and `[numerical-(whatever)]` tags.

Comment: M. I don't think there is a way we can replace one tag with two. So some one will have to go through the numerical linear algebra tag and re-tag every one of them manually.

Comment: I've made numerical-methods and numerical-analysis synonyms.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Willie.

Answer (score 2):

[recursion-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursion-theory) (1 question) should be merged as a synonym of [computability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computability) (36+ questions).  Some people also use [recursive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursive) for questions about computability; I guess someone will have to look at those by hand, because that last tag could also be about recurrence relations or other forms of recursion.

Comment: My mistake, sorry...

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable tag name, we just seem to have started on "computability" first. Do I understand correctly that after they are merged, if someone else uses "recursion-theory" the software will replace it with "computability" automatically? That would be ideal.

Comment: @Carl: I believe that is not merging but rather tag synonyms.

Comment: @Asaf: is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @Carl: No, I am certain Jeff can answer that, though. One of the mods as well. This was the reason I used "believe" :-)

Comment: @Asaf and Carl, there are two different ways to do tag merges: with synonyms turned on or off. With it on, it will behave as Carl described in the second comment above. With it off, the tag can be created anew. (There are, in some cases, good reasons for doing that.)

Comment: I've made recursion-theory as a synonym of computability. Someone better informed will have to look at recursive by hand.

Comment: @Willie: Thanks. I have been looking at the "recursive" ones, but I try to just do one at a time to avoid flooding the main page.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a big fan of the tag [big-picture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-picture). Part of its purpose can be absorbed into the tag [intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuition). The other part of its purpose probably just shouldn't be: I think if you are asking for the big picture in the sense beyond mathematical intuition, your question will be more often better served

- By looking the subject up in an encyclopedia
- By rephrasing it to be more focused and answerable.

(In short, I think the concept of "big-picture" encourages questions that are more ambiguous and vague.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [special-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-functions) tag (107 questions) and there are [gamma-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-function) (32 questions) and [theta-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theta-functions) (3 questions).

In a perfect world, the two latter tags would be specifications of the former. However, there are various uses of these names, specifically, the gamma function is also used for the somewhat related gamma-distribution in probability, specifically [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47008/moment-generating-function-of-gamma-distribution), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/how-do-i-figure-out-what-kind-of-distribution-this-is) and (sort of) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/is-there-an-analytic-solution-for-the-density-function-of-this-complex-random-var).

Recently, there were a few questions tagged [theta-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theta-functions) that had to do with the Bachmann-Landau $\Theta$ appearing in asymptotics ("... grows asymptotically as fast as ...").

I suggest:

1. Let's get rid of [theta-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theta-functions) (delete it, no substitution/merge) and disallow its use in the future for being too specific.
2. Leave [gamma-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-function) since it is used frequently enough.

Alternatively to 2. one could also think about making [gamma-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-function) a synonym of [special-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-functions) at the risk of having to re-tag some probabilistic questions manually (even if that tag wouldn't be completely out of place, IMO).

Comment: I suppose you took care of the asymptotic $\Theta$s? I agree with (1), and am inclined to agree with the alternative to (2).

Comment: @Willie: Yes, I did take care of the asymptotic $\Theta$s.

Answer (score 2):

We all appreciate the importance of [intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intersection) but how needed is this tag?

Comment: Almost 70 questions are using this tag at the moment, so it will take some work to remove it. (If that will be the outcome of voting on your answer.)

Answer (score 2):

What about [convention](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convention)? One question with no votes and no answers has it as an only tag, the rest - I think - it can be removed completely.

Or is it that mods here still cannot delete a tag?

Comment: We cannot delete a tag. To have the tags removed we have to retag all the questions or merge it into another one. And it is not all **that** bad compared to others. I find it hard to justify to myself why it must be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I should have brought this up a few days ago when the tag had just been created, but I don't think [pronunciation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) satisfies the Qiaochu criterion, "Can you imagine a person classifying a tag as either interesting or ignored?"

Comment: I personally would keep the tag, but I neither upvoted nor downvoted your answer yet. (If I had to decide I would keep it, but I am not entirely sure.) If we would decide to get rid of this tag, wouldn't merging in into some bigger tag for "language-related" questions (or renaming and adding other questions) be better? Although I am not sure what a good name for such tag would be, apart from pronunciation we have several questions related to translations of mathematical terms (and probably some other similar questions could be found).

Answer (score 2):

[difference-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference-equations) seems to be used for essentially the same kind of thing as [recurrence-relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recurrence-relation).

Comment: There was a suggestion to synonymize in [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/about-the-questions-tagged-difference-equations-or-recurrence-relations). It received some support (two upvotes), but it has not been discussed too much.

Answer (score 2):

After retagging two questions, [quadratic-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratic-equation) (10q) is now ripe for merging with [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus).

**Edit**: As pointed out by zyx, [quadratics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratics) already exists. Probably better to merge it into that one (or perhaps merge both into [quadratic-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratic-equations), but not every question about quadratics involves an equation).

Comment: The tag description for 221 question (quadratics) is that it is about quadratic equations, so that tag should rather be merged  into (quadratic-equation).

Answer (score 2):

https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/theorem-provers/info links to [automated-theorem-proving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automated-theorem-proving), which has no summary or tag wiki and appears indistinguishable.

#### Edit

The [computer-assisted-proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-assisted-proofs) tag also has no tag wiki, and may also be a candidate for merging.

Answer (score 2):

> **Resolved:** [hat](/questions/tagged/hat) has been merged into (and made a synonym of) [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash).

I am thinking of merging the meta-tag [hat](/questions/tagged/hat) into [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash) (without synonymising).  All of our [hat](/questions/tagged/hat) questions deal with the 2013 Winter Bash, and IMHO it is unlikely that any future [hat](/questions/tagged/hat) questions will come up outside of a future Winter Bash.

While I could unilaterally enact this change, I'm hoping I can get one or two upvotes here before doing so (or be told a good reason why I should not).

Comment: I have suggested that these two tags could be synonyms in the tagging chatroom. See [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12694544#12694544) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12711564#12711564).

Comment: @Martin: My preference would be to simply get rid of [meta-tag:hat] by emptying it via merging, and then let it be deleted. Is there a reason you think [meta-tag:hat] should be preserved at all (even as a synonym of another tag)?

Comment: IMO it is possible that someone would create ([meta-tag:hat]) again, if they have a question about hats. (And they do not notice the tag ([meta-tag-winter-bash]).)

Comment: @Martin: I guess if there is ever a non-Winter-Bash reason to have a [meta-tag:hat] tag, a mod can always [remove the synonym](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86066/214632).  I'll go ahead and do all this presently.

Answer (score 1):

In continuation to my quest to sort out [cardinals] and [large-cardinals] (after accepting the fact there is no way these two will be merged) without bumping the hell out of many questions:

The following should be switched to/added as [large-cardinals]

- [On the definition of weakly compact cardinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198)
- [Real-measurable cardinals that are not measurable ones](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5602)
- [Proving $V_{\kappa}$ is a model of ZFC for inaccessible $\kappa$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14446)

While the following should be taken off [large-cardinals]

- [Is there a known well ordering of the reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6501) (which has nothing to do with cardinals to begin with, actually)
- [Examples of sets whose cardinalities are $\aleph_{n}$, or any large cardinal. (not assuming GCH)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10096) (which has [cardinals])

Comment: Asaf, as far as I know I can't change the tags on specific questions without bumping them.  I can only merge all of one tag into another.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I see. In that case, I guess it's best to leave things as they are perhaps. Or just go along with my original idea and merge cardinals and large-cardinals ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to merge [analytic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic) (only six posts) with [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis).

Comment: at least two of those needs to be retagged if we follow your proposal, as they are actually questions of real analyticity, which is quite very different from complex-analysis. As it currently is, I don't see sufficient reason to actually go through with the merge.

Comment: @Willie: Right, I hadn't looked carefully enough. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't we all [mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematicians) in one way or another?

Well, not all of us. However these six questions here hardly make a point in favor of this tag.

Comment: The questions in that tag has a spread. Some are about the profession of being a mathematician, and some are about historical famous mathematicians. The latter can probably be safely retagged into (math-history). Is there a better tag for the former?

Comment: @Willie: Of course. (soft-question) :-)

Comment: I am in favor of keeping the tag. However, @Willie asked about appropriate tag for questions *about the profession of being a mathematician*. The tag [tag:advice] seems reasonable to me. (Although I did not find many questions of this kind - perhaps some questions had already been retagged.)

Answer (score 1):

Do we *really* need [continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuity)? I mean, a good deal of mathematics is essentially about continuity...

This tag seems a wee bit undefined; overly broad; and all in all irritating.

Comment: IIRC this tag has been introduced by Srivatsan; see the chat transcript [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2885045#2885045). I can imagine it as a suitable tag for some questions about equivalent definitions of continuity; or sequential continuity vs. continuity.

Comment: I wonder why you have a gripe with (continuity) and introduce (compactness) which is at least as broad... :)

Comment: @t.b. I had a problem with this tag, but now I have less problem with it. This post is *old*!

Comment: I see... Forced yourself into a different tagging model, I presume.

Comment: @t.b. Not quite, it is just that the inductive process generating the model is never done, so with time new things are added and truth values change. No forcing... Yet!

Comment: well yes, there is forcing: you force *me* (the continuum tuberculosis) to live with (compactness) which makes me independent :)

Comment: @t.b. Well as long as I don't have to force myself to do things, I am good.

Answer (score 1):

[powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powers) should be merged with [exponentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exponentiation) and should henceforth be regarded a synonym or similar term.

I also suggest the creation of the synonyms [exponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exponents) <strike>and (indices) and even (orders)</strike> if possible but that may result in a confusion with [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) maybe.

Comment: I will decline the "indices" synonym, since there are many other uses of the term. "exponents" I think is not strictly necessary, since users with javascript enabled will see "exponentiation" suggested if they start typing the first few letters of "exponents".

Comment: (orders) is a bad idea, also, as you already noted. In any case, I just created the mapping (powers) -> (exponentiation) and did the merge.

Comment: @WillieWong: Acknowledged and I thank you, on behalf of the entire stackexchange community, for your dedicated efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Can we make [ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratio) go bye-bye?

Comment: Bye-bye where? Just kill, or merge?

Comment: I don't know, what do you think?

Comment: I would say kill, probably. What could it merge with?

Answer (score 1):

[RESOLVED]

The tag [probabilistc-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probabilistc-method) is misspelled (should be [probabilistic-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probabilistic-method)).

Am I right to think such a correction requires Moderator intervention?

Comment: I just manually retagged the questions to the more correct [tag:probabilistic-method] tag.  This seems to be the appropriate action as per [this MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/214632).  (Clearly this did not require moderator intervention.)

Comment: Thanks, the only drawback is that tag wiki has to be recreated.  I'm on it.

Comment: Ooops.  Didn't notice that there was a tag-wiki.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few comments:

I think that [Sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sum) should be removed or at least be made a synonym of Series. But probably remove it.

I don't know what [Untagged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is? Maybe it is the same as Tag-removed? Probably should be removed.

I don't see the point of [Relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relations). It seems totally arbitrary, and I see no advantage to having it.

Comment: I think the point of untagged is that, the question is untagged. If you remove the untagged tag, it is still untagged, so ... (also, it is different from tag-removed. tag-removed does not mean that the tag is removed from the question, but that the tag has been removed from the list of available tags. That option is now obsolete by the new tag rename and tag merge/synonym systems.)

Comment: Which means that the way to fix untagged would be to actually give them tags, manually, one by one. (One way for untagged questions to occur is when a question was migrated from another site, and on that site it was using only tags which we do not have here.)

Comment: The relations tag may have been used for several different things. Looking at the list of questions it is not obvious to me what you want to merge it into. It will have to be dealt with by hand.

Comment: I've dealt with (sum). And am working through (untagged) by hand. There are at least a few that I don't know how to tag (partially being really off topic).

Comment: Thanks, those were just some oddballs I noticed. :)

Comment: I believe relations might be useful. Some time ago I have created tag-wiki and tag-excerpt to indicate the intended use of this tag, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/relations/info).

Answer (score 0):

The [finitism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finitism) has only two questions, and should be merged/synonymized with [philosophy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy).

Comment: If the fact that the past four posts are mine is problematic I will be happy to simply edit further requests into this post (or another).

Comment: I think that it's better not to give more than one proposal in one post, unless they are closely related. Otherwise it is not clear what an upvote/downvote on such post means. (It is upvote for all proposals? For some of them?)

Comment: @Martin: Huh? I think you commented on the wrong answer... :-)

Comment: It was my (somewhat belated) comment to *If ..., I will be happy to simply edit further requests into this post.*

Answer (score 0):

[simplicial-stuff](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplicial-stuff)? Seriously? -stuff tag?

Comment: I think we owe that to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/simplicial-stuff one of the very first questions was tagged this way and the tag remained: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/691/simplicial-objects

Comment: I've creared this one (modeling MO, indeed), but I'm open to suggestions -- what do you propose, actually?

Comment: @Theo: Doesn't make it right, I say :-)

Comment: @Grigory: I have no idea. However -stuff sounds weird.

Comment: @Grigory: Almost, but not quite: http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/45433/revisions, I think we share responsibility ;-)

Comment: @Asaf: I don't think it's *that* bad. The thing is that there is lots of simplicial stuff out there and it is hard to come up with a good alternative.

Comment: ...But I think, we need a tag wiki for this one (maybe later -- there are too few questions so far, but still).

Comment: @Grigory: Well, I don't know. Googling for `simplicial sets site:math.stackexchange.com` gives me quite a few hits and many of them would be appropriately tagged as (simplicial-stuff), I counted at least a dozen questions that should be tagged this way.

Comment: @Grigory: Okay I overestimated massively. I'm now through the list and only found the two (the one retagged by you and the one I retagged).

Comment: @Theo: [simplical-objects] maybe?

Comment: No, I don't think this is descriptive enough. It's more about the morphisms (as usual). @Grigory: What do you think of [simplicial-methods]?

Comment: @Theo For me [simplicial-methods] is more like when [simplicial-stuff] is applied to study something else (simplicial methods in topology, homological algebra, whatever) — so for questions about model structure on simplicial preasheaves [simplicial-stuff] seems to be slightly more natural. But I'm not sure, maybe it's OK (but I don't really see how it's better).

Comment: @Grigory: That's right. I only prefer it because it has a slightly more serious ring to it. I'm fine with [simplicial-stuff]. The AMS MSC doesn't seem to help much either.

Comment: @Theo, @Grigory: You guys understand my grievance with the -stuff suffix, right? It's like I will tag something like [set-stuff]. What about [simplicial-categories]?

Comment: @Asaf: I wonder if simplicial categories would be [too ambiguous](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+category)

Comment: Yes I do. Maybe one should ask about it on meta.MO because 1. there might be more need to do something about it as there are more than 100 questions tagged this way (as opposed to currently 4 here) 2. there might be more experts that could come up with good ideas for alternatives. On the other hand, one could simply split this probably rarely used tag up into [simplicial-sets], [model-categories], and maybe [simplicial-methods] and introduce further tags as needed.

Comment: @Theo: I am very much against splitting rarely used tags into even scarcer tags.

Comment: @GrigoryM: can I convince you to please write a TagWiki for (simplicial-stuff), and perhaps look over the current collection of questions tagged as such? I feel that some users are misusing it for questions about "simplex" in general, but I am not really familiar with the scope of this tag.

Comment: @Willie: I thought this tag is for ... stuff ;-)

Comment: A few in particular I am not sure about: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262999/hypervolume-under-the-square-of-an-n-simplex http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247080/root-mean-square-distance-between-two-simplices http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309468/inner-product-between-certain-vectors-on-a-simplex

Comment: @WillieWong I really hoped someone better qualified would do it, but looks like I have to try anyway (without tag wiki it's frequently misused)...

Answer (score 0):

***Edit: I think that the conclusion is that we should keep this tag.***

Is there a need for a [tensor-products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensor-products) tag? Currently there are two questions under it, but knowing the various generalities in which one can consider tensor products suggest that this tag may accumulate a lot of questions with different assumptions.

It would be good if users remember to also tag with an appropriate subject tag to help clarify. Maybe a reminder is in order in the Tag Wiki?

Comment: Actually, why not? I think tensor products are among the most difficult things one encounters in linear algebra (or wherever one sees them first) and tagging a few more questions thus may be *really* helpful for some. (but maybe I misunderstand the purpose of tagging yet again). By the way there are now seven questions and all tagged this way by the OP except for one that you retagged from tensors.

Comment: @Theo: I was not sure tensor products should refer to linear/multilinear algebra (or functional analysis), or modules/rings, or vector bundles, or monoidal categories, or maybe all? Perhaps we should specify in the wiki that one should also tag appropriately depending on which subject in which one encounters the tensor product?

Comment: I wrote a first version of a possible tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: @Theo: looks good. I edited it slightly to include a one-line blurb about what tensor products are (to fit the space constraint I used the universal property version). I think we can keep this tag then.

Comment: Very good, I didn't see how to fit that in... I suggested some commas.

Comment: I just observed that we have (tensors) and (tensor-products) now. What do you think about this? While tensors are probably a thing I missed in the tag-wiki it will not be obvious to all users how tensors (you know what I mean: $R_{ijkl}$ and pals) relate to tensor products. Should we make a synonym or keep a special tag for these index-laden beasts?

Comment: @Theo: I think the two should be two separate tags. But some of the questions in (tensors) should be retagged to (tensor-products). I am thinking that there would be some more applied-oriented questions where tensors are defined as "higher rank vectors with certain transformation properties under coordinate changes".

Comment: That's exactly what I meant to say. I'll go and re-tag some of them now, okay?

Comment: @Theo Thanks. There are around 12 or so, I think? I've also written a blurb for the exerpt, please see if it can be improved.

Comment: I read your tag wiki and I like it. I think with the one question you just caught the tagging seems to be consistent on both sides now. Can you somehow squeeze in a cross-reference back to (tensors) in the (tensor-products) wiki? But maybe it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Do we really need [parity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parity) around? While at it, [mapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapping) seems a bit redundant too.

Lastly, [transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation) seems like it could be renamed to be [linear-transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-transformation) except perhaps a small handful which can be easily corrected manually.

Comment: The (transformation) tag is an extremely bad one. Not all of the items in it are linear-transformations, it will require sorting through by hand. Someone seems to have dealt with mapping. I am not sure about (parity). It is a valid, named concept in mathematics. But with only 4 questions in it, it is not looking like it is too useful.

Comment: @Willie: My sentiments exactly.

Comment: Oops, (mapping) was not dealt with. There seems to have been a glitch the last time I checked, because now it looks like it has 9 question.

Comment: @Willie: It seems that just as you finished with (mappings) it came back, along with its brother (hash-function), both seem out of place (to the site, not to the question).

Comment: You could have just dealt with mappings too. You know. OTOH, I've never dealt with hash-function. Since non-research-level theoretical computer science is technically on topic, I don't think we should do anything about hash-function.

Comment: @Willie: Just removing seems bland and tasteless, I was unsure what to do. I figured I could either ping you here, or flag the post which would probably be a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

In the comments thread to [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/2801#2801) the question came up what to do with the rather ugly [manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold). I don't like that tag very much, as it seems to me that it should be split up into [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry) and [differential-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-topology).

From a quick glance on the manifold-questions, I think the least intrusive way to do it is:

1. retag those questions that are *not* [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry)
2. merge [manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold) into [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry).

Willie made the point

> No, [manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold) should not be merged into [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry): manifolds are not required to have a smooth structure. Low dimensional topology has a set of tools separate from higher and lower dimensional topology. In one and two dimensions, one can always equip manifolds with a smooth structure, and those smooth structure always give rise to Riemannian/conformal structures, so topology is completely determined by geometry. In higher dimensions the topology is too malleable that a lot of weird stuff can happen. 3 and 4 dimensions is "just right".

Still I don't understand why one needs three tags: [manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold), [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry), [differential-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-topology).

Comment: While I don't like the tag (manifold) too, I don't really think that just using smooth manifold makes a question (differential-geometry) — like, you know, most of the questions with numbers are not (number-theory). So we'll have to manually retag _most_ of these questions, I'm afraid.

Comment: Actually, that comment you cited was mostly to "educate" :) Asaf. While I agree that manifold is an ugly tag, to properly divvy it up we need to probably split it into (smooth-manifolds) (topological-manifolds) and (PL-manifolds). Also, I've always been a bit puzzled by the (differential-geometry) vs (differential-topology) distinction. While I know well that there is a strong distinction at the deeper levels (connections, vector bundles, and what nots), most of the elementary questions about the two subjects asked on this site can equally well fit into either.

Comment: @Willie I'd say (differential-geometry) is when one uses some metrical properties (hence connections, curvature and so on).

Comment: @Grigory: right. [Ryan Budney seems to agree](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/53782/revisions)

Comment: @Grigory and Theo: in the abstract, I agree. But this distinction is going to be hard to explain to a 3rd year undergrad who has taken only a first course in differential geometry, which at various universities may mean actually differential topology, differential geometry, or even Riemannian geometry. (To put it differently: I perfectly understand and appreciate the distinction of the two subjects. I am just not optimistic that the two distinct tags would be used properly.)

Comment: @Willie: Okay, I can live with that and I see the problem. But: can we please rename (manifold) into (manifolds)?

Comment: @Theo: I didn't do that already? Shame on *me*! It must've gotten lost in the queue.

Comment: @Willie (re: not optimistic) Probably you're right, but (editing) tag wikis could help a little...

Comment: @Grigory I agree. Ideally if Ryan Budney (or someone with a better idea of what precisely differential topology is about) would be so kind to write the (differential-topology) wiki. The (differential-geometry) one looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

From the recently opened tags, there are several tags whose usefulness is unclear. I'm posting this short list here because I see no reason to start a full thread about it, but I am also listing all the tags at once because there is quite a few of them.

If you remove some of the tags, please strike them off the list (or mark them somehow to signify that you've done so.)

1. [golden-ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golden-ratio)
2. [complemented-subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complemented-subspaces)
3. [smooth-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smooth-numbers)
4. [hom-order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hom-order)
5. [inverse-semigroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverse-semigroups)
6. [quiver](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quiver)
7. <strike>(foundations)</strike>
8. [fractional-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractional-calculus)
9. [rubiks-cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube)  $\checkmark$ (judging by Willie's retagging it seems this one is a keeper)
10. [recursion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursion) $\leftarrow$ Someone please look into this one, the tag itself is growing and it is better to mass-retag when there are only five questions, not when there are 20.
11. <strike>(pseudonoise)</strike>
12. <strike>(lfsr)</strike>

On that list it is possible that quivers deserve their own tag, and the question whether or not we want a tag for general foundations questions is also open. I also think that [recursion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursion) is a bad tag  because we already had problems with recursion related tag names and there was quite an agreement that those are unclear.

Lastly, I think that we should all agree that tags should be at least a bit meaningful. So [lfsr](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lfsr) should probably be renamed if not removed.

Comment: Hmm, ideally, [tag:rubiks-cube] should be under [tag:recreational-mathematics], but it does seem that we have already a number of Rubik questions that maybe a separate tag is justifiable...

Comment: On that note: should the time come that we suddenly have a lot of questions on linear feedback shift registers, I'd not be surprised why some might want to use the acronym instead...

Comment: @J.M.: You crossed off [lfsr] but there are still three questions tagged. Do you intend to retag them, or just think that the tag should stay?

Comment: Hit too early. Ought to be okay now...

Comment: Seeing that there are +10 questions specifically about Rubiks cubes, it may be worth keeping. (Up until recently I was with JM in thinking that it should be recreational-maths, but the number has gone up a bit in the past month or so; granted some of them are not the best of questions. At the very least it will help people search for duplicates.)

Comment: Note that also some of the "possibly useful" (in the sense of describing a mathematical concept) tags can be left alone: if after 6 months there aren't much usage, the orphaned tags will be automatically cleaned up. If usage goes up, well, maybe they could stay.

Comment: @Willie: Single question means orphaned tag?

Comment: Maybe it is not the best terminology, but Jeff uses it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/155238) so I do too.

Comment: @Willie: Ah, I see. [recursion] and [fractional-calculus] are both with more than one question each. The former is troublesome in light of previous discussions about recursion named tags being ambiguous; the latter... I just don't know about.

Comment: I think [fractional-calculus] may deserve to stay. [recursion] however, is a can of worms. It'd be great if we can get Henning or someone else more familiar with the subject to comment on it.

Comment: I don't know; fractional calculus is interesting, but not terribly popular. But there is no way of telling if we might get a torrent of differintegral questions tomorrow, after all...

Comment: @Willie: my feelings about [tag:recursion] aren't too different from my feelings for [tag:inverse]; somewhat overloaded that maybe it's not a very good tag to have.

Comment: @J.M.: I ran a search on torrent search engines, and it seems unlikely we'll find one tomorrow... :-P could you alert Henning to this thread and fill him in on the recursion issue? It seems we'll all benefit from his advice here.

Comment: I like (quiver) in the sense that I'd have nothing against a (quivers) tag and there's a [bunch of questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=quiver) that could be tagged this way. Points 1-4 could use deletion and 5 is at least debatable. Fractional calculus shows up occasionally.

Comment: @Willie: I think some action is needed on [recursion], with seven questions I completely agree that this is a can of worms and should be excised like that theorem about homology groups and simplicial stuff...

Comment: @Asaf: I've superpinged Henning. My main problem is that I am not sure how to retag those questions. Do they belong in functional-equations?

Comment: @Willie -- "recursion" is problematic as a tag because it means quite different things to different people. For programmers (and sometimes computer scientists), a "recursive" function is a complex and advanced technique, known to confuse the hell out novice programmers -- so one can talk about keeping things nice and non-recursive. On the other hand, for logicians (and sometimes computer scientists), "recursive" functions are a particularly _nice_ and simple class of function -- namely they computable ones. This will make it difficult to keep the use of the tag consistent.

Comment: @Henning, Willie: I think that this is why [recursion] was previously split into transfinite-recursion and recurrence-relations tags.

Comment: Looking over (recursion), the three oldest questions would fit well simply as (recurrence-relations). Then there's a linear equation which the OP seems to have thought was "recursive" because the unknown appeared on both sides of the equals sign. The two newest questions are about understanding a recursively defined function. If anything deserves a (recursion) tag, that would be it, but I still think it would be prohibitively difficult to keep clean. I'm not quite sure how to retag them, touch.

Comment: On further thought, the only thing that prevents the two newest questions from being (recurrence-relations) is that the questions use pseudocode rather than `\begin{cases}` to define the recurrence. That is probably not sufficient reason to tag them differently. The trouble is more how we can make the tag easier discoverable for the next new user with a similar question. Is it possible to make a pseudo-tag that can't be applied to questions but still displays an excerpt that point at more relevant ones?

Comment: @Henning: I do not know if we can make a pseudo-tag. The closest (that I know of) we can do is to make [recursion] a synonym of [recurrence-relations] and rely on people to retag with that tag is _not_ appropriate.

Comment: @Willie: I am all for this idea.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that most questions on [hopf algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=hopf+algebra) are tagged [quantum-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-groups). Today the tag [hopf-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hopf-algebras) was created (in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164881/the-exterior-product-in-the-hopf-algebra)). Should these two tags by synonyms?

As I know nothing about these two notions, I hope someone more familiar with them could be able to tell what is correct thing to do.

Comment: Even though the most common occurrence of Hopf algebra problems will be from quantum groups, they also turn up in the study of algebraic groups and to some extend of Lie algebras (via the universal enveloping algebra), and as such, the tags are not quite synonyms.

Comment: Based on Tobias comment, keeping the tag seems to be reasonable. I've added one more question to [tag:hopf-algebras] to avoid automatic removal (the tags containing only one question are removed after 6 months). I'll leave the activity related to this tag for people who know more about this area.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that [exponential-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exponential-function) should be folded into [exponentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exponentiation).

Comment: I had assumed that the former refers to the function $\exp$, and the latter to arithmetic operation $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$. I see that they are used inter-changeably now.

Comment: also, what do you feel about the [tag:powers]?

Comment: Blah, that's another thing that needs to be sorted out. It seems they all are being used interchangeably. Messy...

Answer (score 0):

> **Resolved:** [miscellaneous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miscellaneous) no longer exists: may it <s>rot in hell</s> rest in <s>pieces</s> peace.

A recently created [miscellaneous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miscellaneous) tag should probably be deleted before someone uses it.

Comment: A tag with no questions associated with it will be automatically deleted.  In fact, [tag:miscellaneous] has already been deleted from the system.  Tag-links (such as I edited into the answer, and the one in the previous sentence) always goes somewhere, even nonsense tags like [tag:untendablestuffman] which clearly don't exist... yet.

Answer (score -1):

Why do we have both [simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplex) and [simplicial-stuff](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplicial-stuff)?

Comment: `simplex` should go away, but not all those problems belong under "simplicial-". Problems involving simplex method should be tagged `optimization`; integration over a simplex belongs under `multivariable-calculus` and `integration`. By the way, there ought to be a better tag name than `-stuff`; maybe `simplicial-objects`?

Comment: @PostNoBills: why should (simplex) go away? Simplices are perfectly normal mathematical objects. The (simplicial-stuff) [has some history](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2463/1543).

Comment: @Willie: I thought that the main stuff in simplicial stuff was simplices...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: evidently not, at least from what I can glean from the discussion on that thread.

Comment: @Willie: Well, at least in theory... In that case, what do we need the simplex tag for?

Comment: @AsafKaragila perhaps for questions about actual simplices? There are some nice and elementary geometry stuff about simplices which are not as highfaluting as the stuff usually considered "simplicial stuff".

Comment: [Tag wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/simplicial-stuff/info) for 'simplicial-stuff' explicitly asks 'Please do not use for questions about geometry of simplices nor about triangulations'.

Answer (score -2):

Can we please delete [proof-writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-writing). This is a subjective tag.

Comment: I don't think so. There are legitimate on-topic questions about how to write/present proofs which are more or less independent of what the proof happens to be _about_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: How to write/present proofs is a bit subjective, isn't it? All we get it someone's opinion about some very (likely) localized problem (from what few questions I saw). Can you please point me to some question for which the proof-writing tag is necessary and which might be not be too localized? Note: I am just trying to understand why the tag is there, I might end up agreeing with you :-)

Answer (score -3):

While writing up a question, I found [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition), with [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) more favored. I'd recommend a tag synonym.

Comment: I vote against this merge. I just think that the two tags should remain separate.

Comment: @Asaf: Could you explain on what grounds, so I can understand your reasoning?

Comment: @Michael: I just think that there is a distinction between questions about terminology and questions about definitions.

Comment: @Asaf: I think to most questioners and answerers, the distinction is not that wide. I see some [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/36346/541) in [tag:terminology] that ask about the meanings of words, and I also see [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/17739/541) in [tag:definition] that ask about the name of such-and-such. At the core, they are both about meanings.

Comment: @Michael: By that logic one could say that all questions should be tagged under set-theory (and sadly, many newcomers do that for no apparent reason). Terminology and definitions are dual notions, in the former you ask about the names for a given definition while in the latter you ask about the definition of a given name.

Comment: @Asaf: Do you see a situation where a questioner/answerer is looking for one to the exclusion of the other? I myself am unable to see a case where you'd like to search for one and not the other. I dislike appealing to definitions (pun not intended), but the [tag wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/terminology/info) for terminology implies that it is also where you would ask definition-based questions.

Comment: @Asaf and @Michael : perversely I agree with Asaf that there is a subtle distinction between terminology and definition. However, I won't go so far to say that they shouldn't be synonyms for tagging purposes--the distinction is rather subtle, and the constant retagging of questions from one to the other may not be worth the effort. Instead of "duking it out" here in the comment threads though, may I suggest one of you start a new Meta.Math topic on this? Clearly there is *some* contention to whether this change should be implemented or not, so it is better if we discuss it in public.

Comment: @Willie: Very well, however in the next day or so I will be mostly incapacitated to answer, so I will have to ask and wait for me to recover from today's wonders before making a decision. Also, perversely?? :-P

Comment: @Asaf: as you probably correctly surmised, that adverb applies to the "I agree with Asaf" part and not to the part about existence of subtle distinction. `:-)`

Comment: @Willie: That is a good idea, and I will do as you suggest.

Comment: @Asaf: When you're ready in the next day or so, do you want to post to meta.math? I'm thinking we make it community wiki and have a pro answer and a con answer, which people can choose via upvote (but ignore downvotes).

Comment: @Michael: I will post a question, you can write the pro merge, I will write the con merge. No actual need for CW since this is meta anyway.

Comment: @Willie, Michael: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-should-we-handle-tags-terminology-notation-definition might be relevant and not require any new thread?

Comment: @Asaf: Can the question be revived easily?

Comment: @Michael: I don't know any other way than checking. Just posting an answer or edit should do the trick.

Comment: @Asaf and Michael: bumped.

Comment: @Willie, Michael: What have we decided about this? Should there be a merge, or not? I'm still against, if that matters.

Comment: @Asaf: I think for now I'll leave it be and not merge.

Comment: @Asaf: Yeah, I think the community seemed to prefer the status quo.

Answer (score -3):

I propose the following [tag synonym<strike>s</strike>](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=creator):

2. [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) $\leftarrow$ [conditional-probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-probability) , because the topics seem related enough and  all but one of five questions in the latter share the first as well.
3. <strike>(elementary-number-theory) $\leftarrow$    (divisibility),
   because also divisibility appears in the tag wiki of the first.</strike>
4. <strike>(combinatorics)  $\leftarrow$  (combinatorial-designs), all questions from the latter tag share the first as well.</strike>

Comment: *Synonym* is not a synonym of *subset*. The tag synonym system is for when two tags refer to the same concept. Even if every conditional probability question is a probability question, not every probability question is a conditional probability question.

Comment: @RahulNarain ok, then please vote down the corresponding tag synonym proposal, if you think we need both tags...What about the others?

Comment: What about the others? Do you think every elementary number theory question is a divisibility question, and every combinatorics question is a combinatorial designs question?

Comment: No the other way. Maybe I got the concept wrong...but why is counting (primes for example) synonym to combinatorics?

Comment: @draks: about counting, that is because for the most part when the synonym was proposed, the questions tagged "counting" were mostly about "count how many cases" which is by definition combinatorics.

Comment: @Rahul: I think the fact that there is a master and a slave tag in the synonym system means that we don't have to be so strictly observant of the $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$ rule. By draks' proposal anytime someone tags (divisibility) the question would be retagged (elementary-number-theory), and not the other way around, so I don't really think [you objection](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/8691#comment29322_8645) is that serious.

Comment: @Willie: That makes it impossible to indicate that a question is about combinatorial designs, or about divisibility. Is that desirable?

Comment: @Rahul: that was a general comment saying that just because $A$ is a strict subset of $B$ should not prevent a synonym from being created from $A\to B$. See for example JM's proposal below of "(trigonometric-identities) -> (trigonometry)" which got approved by user votes. (You have 10K, so you can see it.) Whether a tag should stand should be judged by other factors than just "it is not exactly the same as an existing tag".

Comment: @Rahul: my opinion is that the (combinatorial-designs) tag should stay, while (divisibility) should go. But as my votes are binding and there's no universal agreement, I'll refrain from casting a vote either way. (conditional-probability) could probably stay for now to be revisited later. I'm not convinced either way. Lastly, tag synonyms _can be undone_, as has happened with (physics) and (mathematical-physics). (Though sometimes it requires a little bit of retagging afterward to sort through the changes.)

Comment: @Willie: OK, I take back my objection to (divisibility). And (conditional-probability) seems like a pretty useless tag; I wonder if we shouldn't just delete it instead of making it a synonym. I guess I overreacted to the fact that the only rationale given for the suggested synonyms was that they were subsets of another tag.

Comment: Deleting the tag (conditional-probability) was a most unwise decision (whose rationalizations above do not hold water and make for a rather odd reading). People, just grab any modern probability theory textbook and tick the chapters in it on this very subject... Was the deletion acted upon by *two users* in all, if I read correctly?

Comment: I will add that there is a new post about the synonym between (conditional-probability) and (probability) in the 2018 thread: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27653/tag-management-2018#28753