# Tag renaming: [rings] to [ring-theory]

Tags: discussion, tagging

Well, the title says it all.

I think that the tag [rings] is somewhat inappropriate, and [ring-theory] should be used instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll do this right after I mention that in the future such requests should go into [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms).  (Can we sticky threads here?)

Comment: I think that moderators can add a featured tag in meta to certain questions.