# editing tags ("That title is too short to be useful." (!!))

Tags: support, tagging

We have a tag called "expectancy".  We have none called either "expectation" or "expected value", both standard terms.  The other two ought to redirect to "expected value".  How is that done?

Answer (score 2):

The http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms exists for a reason. `=)`

In the future, please post such requests there. I've just merged [expentancy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expentancy) into [expected-value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expected-value) (which I assume you created?).

Alternatively, when at the page listing all questions of the tag, you can click on "synonyms", which brings you to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/expected-value/synonyms), where you can suggest synonyms for other users to vote on!

Answer (score 1):

We used to have a tag called "expectation," but it was merged with the "probability" tag several months ago.  The record is in the first answer [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms).  There was also a discussion about the merging as an answer to the "tag merging and synonyms" question, but it has been deleted.  (So, unfortunately, Michael can't see it now because of the 10K requirement for viewing deleted posts.)  The most pertinent part is this comment:

> done. I merged expectation into probability, since the tag description for the latter explicitly mentioned expectations. – Willie Wong♦ Apr 6 at 13:12

And that was the essence of the reason for the merger: We decided that the "probability" tag sufficiently covered whatever might be covered by an "expectation" tag.

In keeping with the decision from several months back, I suggest we delete "expectancy" and "expected value" as tags.

Comment: It is, however, listed in the [summary thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/2419#2419), which I really ought to have checked myself.