# A rep. threshold to override the synonyms rep?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, tag-management

Since some of the tags have very little traffic in them, and hardly anyone has even the +5 reputation, and seeing how the moderators are already [busy enough converting old answers to comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917/unearthing-ancient-not-an-answers), is it possible to allow 10k (or some other class of users) to suggests synonyms regardless to the tag reputation?

Comment: You should probably ask this rather on meta.SO, where The Powers That Edit The Code are, no?

Comment: @Mariano: I have no user on meta.SO, nor any intention to have such user anytime soon. However, I do remember that this site is for requests about math.SE, and this is such request.

Comment: Surely, feel free to post it where you want. I was only trying to transmit my experience of being told to post such requests there—no one here, except the Powers That Descend From Time To Time From Meta.SO have any say on what the software lets us or not do.

Comment: @Mariano: If you think this has better place at meta.SO feel free to migrate the question.

Comment: @Mariano That changed a while ago, users are now encouraged to post also network-wide issues on their site metas, if they want to. The SE team also monitors all site metas.

Comment: Of course, it may take the team 4 months to get around to any particular question on this meta.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do in this case is encourage your diamond moderators to periodically peruse the synonyms page ...

https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

... and manually approve any that they know to be correct.

A bad synonym can be fairly dangerous, so we want to be a bit conservative here. You can also lobby for any synonyms you particularly wish to see implemented here on meta, of course -- and over time there will be more users with more upvotes in specific tags.