# Tags [proof-strategy] and [proof-writing]

Tags: discussion, tagging

What are the tags [proof-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy) and [proof-writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-writing) used for?

They feel like [meta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) tags to me.

Instead of adding answers here, please vote on the answers in the tagging [thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1363) here: [proof-strategy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3761), [proof-writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3762).

Comment: [here's the thread that led to the inception of \[proof writing\]](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560/should-there-be-a-proof-writing-tag)

Comment: @t.b.: Thank you!

Comment: A [discussion about proof-strategy tag](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/proof-strategy-tag) from chat.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps an answer is appropriate 3.5 years later?

- The proposal to delete [proof-writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-writing) has the score of -2. The tag is widely misused all the same, but perhaps it is occasionally used correctly.  Let it be for now, though some tag-based warning about its use may be appropriate.
- The proposal to delete [proof-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy) has the score of +9. Browsing the tag, I am unable to find a single recent question that is about "strategy". They are all ordinary questions about proving ordinary things.  (The newer trend is to go all-in with (proof-strategy), (proof-verification), and (proof-writing), possibly with (proof-theory) added for good measure. Because, you know, it's about a proof. The subject matter remains absent from the tags.)

Aryabhata's motion to delete [proof-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy) is long overdue for action.

Comment: Would anything of value be lost if proof-strategy disappeared without a trace? Or is a more nuanced cleanup needed here.

Comment: Nothing would be lost, in my opinion. The questions with this tag are not worse or better than the rest; nor do they belong to any particular subject. It's basically used as a substitute for blacklisted "proof".

Comment: Hmm... In that case, along with burnination, perhaps we need [some disambiguation?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3350/rename-cd-to-cd-command/3356#3356)

Comment: I'm not sure that those using [proof-strategy] actually see the blocking message for "proof"; they may be accepting the first suggestion of auto-complete, sidestepping the warning.  But it wouldn't hurt to explain the "proof" blocking message anyway... Like this: tag "proof" is not allowed. Use proof-writing if you'd like advice on the presentation of your proof, or proof-verification if you'd like feedback on its validity. If you don't have any proof yet, tag the question according to its area of mathematics.

Comment: Here is a post related to @Shog9's comment. [Should we request customized messages for some blacklisted tags?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16750/should-we-request-customized-messages-for-some-blacklisted-tags)

Comment: This has been done. [Please care for the widows and orphans](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged)

Comment: It took less than 9 hours for the tag to be resurrected... I untagged, let's see if we can beat the tag into auto-deletion.