# How to overcome "You can't create this tag" if there is meta agreement?

Tags: support, tagging, retagging

So, in [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10083/43351), I suggested to replace [rootsystem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rootsystem) with [root-system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/root-system). A user suggested [root-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/root-systems) instead, which is indeed better.

So having 7 upvotes and no downvotes, I decided to implement the change. But then I ran into the system:

[image: can't create tag]

How could I ever go about implementing this change if the system prohibits its creation in the first place? Can it only be done by moderators?

(As an aside, I think the red text should say "Your **edit** couldn't be submitted." instead of "question".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask a moderator to perform this change by making a meta post. Moderators can also directly merge the two tags to rename the old tag, which is easier than retagging all old questions by hand.

Comment: And the red text?

Answer (score 3):

I have merged [rootsystem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rootsystem) into [root-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/root-systems).

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: No problem.  Cheers!